# Object reference not set to an instance of an object[Xamarin, IOS] in UiTable

Tags: ios, object, reference, xamarin

I am trying to make my custom UITable view show only images from a different class. everything compiles but as soon as the app opens it crashes and tells me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
Here is my class that is suppose to hold the images : pastebin . com/QDjDVTdm
Here is my custom table cell : http://pastebin.com/G3TLMfe4
and here is my table source : http://pastebin.com/xPDuhBeV

And here is how the table is declared in my view controller:

```
unclass[] lol= new unclass[2];
UITableView _table;

_table = new UITableView{
    Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 30, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height-30),
    Source = new TableSource(lol)
};
_table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
_table.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
_table.EstimatedRowHeight = new nfloat (15.0);
View.AddSubview (_table);
```

Comment: Where exactly does the NullReferenceException get thrown? If the debugger is attached, it should break exactly where the exception gets thrown. If it's not attached, the log should have line numbers.

Comment: It gives me the error in "Table source", in the "cell.UpdateCell (tableItems [indexPath.Row].imager);" line

line 33

Comment: What line? In a debug build there are line numbers in the crash log.

Comment: Okay I see your update. Can you use the debugger to find out exactly what is null when it crashes?

Comment: in the pastern link of table source, the program runs and it crashes at that line (line 33 in table source :http://pastebin.com/xPDuhBeV)

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. You're declaring an array of size 2 (new unclass[2]) but I don't see where you're putting anything in it. So both of the spots in the array will just be null. Put some objects in the array:

lol[0] = new unclass(...);
lol[1] = new unclass(...);

Comment: here is a screenshot of what my debugger shows me : http://i.imgur.com/ozqkpv5.png

Comment: Thank you very much, dont know how i could of overlooked something so simple. thank you ALLOT

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

You're declaring an array of size 2 (new unclass[2]) but I don't see where you're putting anything in it. So both of the spots in the array will just be null. Put some objects in the array:

```
lol[0] = new unclass(...);
lol[1] = new unclass(...);
```